# Wicket 7 [WebPage] - jquery request creating a new instance WebPage

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wicket

My application has a websocket client running on the client side, I'm using websocket to upload files.

I have a wicket WebPage that has two ways to upload USB files(automatic and Input type file)
when my page is instantiated, it's has the instance "X".
When the ajax requests are made by the wicket componets, my page has the instance "X".
When the request are made by javascript code, the processing occurs in "X", but after the processing wicket creates a new instance "Y" without the data processed in "X", and show to user the instance Y. it always occurs when a new ajax(javascript code) request is made.

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
        url : postUrl,
        type : 'post',
        cache : false,
        data :data,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false, 
        complete : function(xhr, status) {
            $("#messagemWs").html("");
            wsBu.stopBusca();
        }
    });
```

Ajax Behavior:

```
public class WsFilesAjaxBehavior extends AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String WS_CALBACK = "my:wsupload.callback";

    private WsFilesAjaxBehaviorCallback callback;

    public WsFilesAjaxBehavior(WsFilesAjaxBehaviorCallback callback) {
    super();
    this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void setCallback(WsFilesAjaxBehaviorCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }



    @Override
    protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
    tag.put(WS_CALBACK, getCallbackUrl().toString());
    super.onComponentTag(tag);
    }

    private void buildFileUploadList(List<FileItem> fileItemsRequest, List<FileUpload> fileItems) {
    for (FileItem fileItem : fileItemsRequest) {
        fileItems.add(new FileUpload(fileItem));
    }
    }

    private void getRequestFiles(final RequestCycle requestCycle, AjaxRequestTarget target) {

    final ServletWebRequest webRequest = (ServletWebRequest) requestCycle.getRequest();

    Map<String, List<FileItem>> multiPartRequestFiles = null;

    try {
        MultipartServletWebRequest multiPartRequest = webRequest.newMultipartWebRequest(Bytes.megabytes(1), "UploadInfo");
        multiPartRequest.parseFileParts();
        multiPartRequestFiles = multiPartRequest.getFiles();
    } catch (FileUploadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        return;
    }

    List<FileUpload> fileUploads  = new ArrayList<>();

    if (multiPartRequestFiles != null && !multiPartRequestFiles.isEmpty()) {
        for (Entry<String, List<FileItem>> entry : multiPartRequestFiles.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        buildFileUploadList(entry.getValue(), fileUploads);
        }
    }


    callback.webSocketCallback(fileUploads, target);


//  target.appendJavaScript("alert('Processado!');");  
    }



    @Override
    protected void respond(AjaxRequestTarget target) {

    RequestCycle requestCycle = RequestCycle.get();
    getRequestFiles(requestCycle, target);
    }
}
```

ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the special Wicket-Ajax request parameters. See the ones sent by Wicket Ajax behaviour for their exact names.

AFAIR they are: Wicket-Ajax=true and Wicket-Base-Url=something.  See wicket-ajax-jquery.js to see how to create the value for the second.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!